# Campo de checkout não aparece no objeto da order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Estou tendo um problema com o objeto order do **wordpress**. Após efetuar a compra, o objeto order não vem com o valor inserido no campo. O campo CPF é criado por mim, segue o código:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  $fields['billing']['billing_cpf'] = array(
      'label'     => __('CPF', 'woocommerce'),
      'required'  => true,
      'class'     => array('input-text'),
      'clear'     => true,
      'type'     => "text",
      "name" => "billing_cpf",
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

O campo aparece na tela, mas seu valor não é enviado no array `$order->data['billing']`.
Como receber o valor dele? Estou utilizando o plugin do **woocommerce**, e criei outro (plugin) para fazer essas mudanças.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver isso, você pode utilizar a função `get_post_meta`, para isso, use a seguinte sintaxe: `get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_cpf', true )`, isso irá retornar o valor inserido no input!